# Bootstrap Angular - Checkbox value is not working

Tags: angular, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am using angular 4 for page design. The checkbox is not getting selected no matter what value I pass, below is my code for same -

```
<div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input type="checkbox" value="false"> No
    </label>
</div>
```

I have tried with `value="true"`, `value=true`, `checked="true"`, `checked=true`. My intention is to use an expression or a dynamic value to set check box selection. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `[checked]="true"` you want this?

Comment: ngModelues `[ngModel]="true"`

Comment: @Aravind Yup that works, thanks for the help, if you put that in answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Jeet Done. (y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per comment,

Use `ngModel`

```
<div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
       <input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="false"> No
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Why the same way it doesn't work for reactive forms if we use formControlName?